# Question on proof of elementary ordinary differential equation theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am self-studying differential equations using MIT's publicly available materials.  I'm afraid I'm not very far along--indeed, I'm just now looking at separable equations.  The published lecture notes for the course present the following theorem:

Let $f(x)$, $g(y)$ be continuous functions on a rectangle $R = \lbrace (x,y): a < x < b, c < y < d\rbrace$ such that $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are never simultaneously zero.  Then there is one and only one solution through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ to the DE $f(x)dx = g(y)dy$, and it is given by $\int_{x_0}^xf(x)dx = \int_{y_0}^yg(y)dy$.

The proof that follows is straightforward, except for one assertion, which just so happens to occur very early in the proof.  The author of the notes writes:  Note that $f(x) \neq 0$ for $a < x < b$ or $g(y) \neq 0$ for $c < y < d$.  **Without loss of generality**, we assume $g(y) > 0$ for $c < y < d$.

It's the 'without loss of generality' that puzzles me.  It's certainly clear that if $g(y) \neq 0$ for $c < y < d$, then $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$ is well-defined everywhere on $R$.  On the other hand, if $g(y) = 0$ somewhere, isn't $\frac{dy}{dx}$ undefined, regardless of the behavior of $f(x)$?  (For what it's worth, the text for the course, Birkhoff and Rota, proves the theorem with the condition that $g(y)$ is continuous between two successive zeros, which would equate to $c$ and $d$ in formulation given by the notes.  It makes no demands, other than continuity, of $f(x)$ whatsoever.)

So:  if $g(y_1) = 0$ for some $y_1 \in (c,d)$, how can the fact that $f(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in (a,b)$ prevent $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$ from being undefined at $(x,y_1)$?  What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps this is what's going on:  Note that $f(x)dx = g(y)dy$ is not actually identical with $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x)}{g(y)}$.  So assume that $g(y) = 0$ for some $y_1 \in (c,d)$ but $f(x) \neq 0$ if $x \in (a,b)$.  No problem - even if $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is undefined at $(x, y_1)$, $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{g(y)}{f(x)}$ is just fine.  In other words, the theorem as presented in the notes is indifferent to whether $y$ is a function of $x$ or $x$ is a function of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my earlier comment, I believe that my mistake was in assuming that $y$ needed to depend on $x$.  Certainly $f(x)dx = g(y)dy$ does not in and of itself imply such a relation.  Thus, if $g(y) = 0$ for some $y_1 \in (c,d)$, then we are given that $f(x) \neq 0$ for any $x \in (a,b)$.  Therefore $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{g(y)}{f(x)}$ is well-defined for all $(x,y) \in R$, and the rest of the theorem follows.  The point, as the conditions state, is that $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ cannot simultaneously be zero.  That is, there exists no point $(x_1,y_1) \in R$ such that $f(x_1) = 0$ and $g(y_1) = 0$, because at such a point neither the idea that $x$ depends on $y$ nor the idea that $y$ depends on $x$ makes sense, and we need to have one or the other.